# custom filter for Fail2Ban

Tags: fail2ban

I have installed fail2ban and I am trying to get it set up to block IP addresses that appear in a certain message that appears in the syslog.  The message in the syslog is:

`racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from 103.14.62.181[11950]`

Usually each message has a different IP address and the number in brackets (port?) is different as well.  It looks like I can create a custom filter by doing the following:

`racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from <HOST>`

But my question is, can I stop there and will fail2ban do its thing, or do I need to specify something like this:

`racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from <HOST>[IDONTKNOWWHATGOESHERE]`

If I need to specify something like the above, what would be the effective wildcard that should appear in the brackets?  The fail2ban documentation about OpenVPN (closest example) shows this:

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN

`* <HOST>:[0-9]{4,5} Connection reset, restarting \[[0-9]{1,2}\]`

It looks like they are using [0-9]{4,5} as a wildcard for the port number.  Would that work in my case, or no?

Am I completely off base with my example for my filter?

The ultimate goal here is to have anything that fails with a 243 exchange error to be added to the IP Tables with a DROP flag.  I may have more questions about my filter and what not after I get the initial question answered.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can stop there and fail2ban will do it's thing. You can test this with the [fail2ban-regex(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fail2ban-regex) utility. The summary is

```
fail2ban-regex [OPTIONS] <LOG> <REGEX> [IGNOREREGEX]
```

so using the work you have done (Note that I had to add a datetime to the start of your provided log entry otherwise it complains.)

```
fail2ban-regex "Mar  3 07:36:19 racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from 103.14.62.181[11950]" "racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from <HOST>"

Running tests
=============

Use regex line : racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from <HOST>
Use single line: Mar  3 07:36:19 racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange ty...

Matched time template MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
Got time using template MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second

Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|- #) [# of hits] regular expression
|  1) [1] racoon: ERROR: Invalid exchange type 243 from <HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
    103.14.62.181 (Mon Mar 03 07:36:19 2014)

Date template hits:
2 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second

Success, the total number of match is 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Lain.  I believe this is going to help out a lot.  So can you confirm that the following will be correct?

Create a custom filter for these events

Comment: @locutusoftron: Yep, I would add a custom filter to filter.d and then configure/enable it in the jail.conf.

Comment: @locutusoftron: SF isn't a forum, you ask a question, get answers and if you want ask more questions. not followups like this. Before continuing. documentation and man pages are your friend - we really value your attempting to figure things out yourself first.

Comment: I found my answer.  Thanks for your assistance lain.